# How do I make sure after reading a file in C#, then storing it in a database, that if I were to re-read it, an error would come up

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

How do I make sure after reading a file in C#, then storing it in a database, that if I were to re-read it, an error would come up because it's in the database and already been stored?

I have to no idea how to open the file and store and make sure it doesn't get re-read again.

Comment: You could probably query prior to insert and react to a row being returned from the query.

Comment: you would need to keep track of the file names you've read... create a table to store that...

Comment: Have a table that tracks filenames/import dates.  Or move the file after importing

Comment: Please show the code you have tried.

Comment: Literally, `if I were to re-read it, an error would come up because it's in the database` sounds impossible: file system and database neither know nor care about each other: "someone" would have to take it into her own hands.

Comment: What range of file sizes are you expecting? Big enough that adding a unique constraint to the relevant column isn't viable? Big enough that keeping a copy of one of the files in memory isn't practical?

Comment: The normal pattern is to have a "Ready To Import" folder and an "Already Imported" folder. You only ever import from the "Ready To Import" folder and when done, move it into the next folder. There isn't a 100% reliable way to recognise if it's the same file. You could try using the filename but someone could accidentally rename it.

Comment: As others have said, moving the file somewhere else after you have processed it is probably the safest way.